# Meteor jsPDF Package Error

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I added [js-pdf package](http://atmospherejs.com/package/js-pdf) to my Meteor app but whenever I run a simple hello world code I get an error:

Code:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Paranyan loves jsPDF");
```

I get:

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jsPDF
click #download-pdf (manageatas.js, line 53)
(anonymous function) (templating.js, line 120)
(anonymous function) (blaze.js, line 2205)
withCurrentView (blaze.js, line 2038)
(anonymous function) (blaze.js, line 2204)
(anonymous function) (blaze.js, line 802)
dispatch (jquery.js, line 4657)
handle (jquery.js, line 4325)
```

I tried with the package installed, I tried downloading the code and adding it to client side folder but I get the same error again ...

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a load of problems with that package too.

Try putting [jspdf.debug.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.debug.js)
somewhere in your code (I have mine in client/thirdparty/ ), get rid of the var from var jsPDF = (function(global) and give it a shot this way.

Make sure to remove the package and other jspdf js files first!

Answer (score 0):

The package appears to be incompatible with recent Meteor versions (which is weird, as it seems to receive updates). I recommend adding jspdf.js manually to your `/client/lib/compatibility` folder.

If you don't want to use `compatibility` folder, you need to ensure the `jsPDF` object is created in global scope, instead as a local variable in a file. Fortunately, it's easy – just remove `var` keyword from its declaration. In other words, line 39 should be:

```
jsPDF = (function () {
```

instead of

```
var jsPDF = (function () {
```

Comment: I tried both options and nothing, the error continues...
It's so strange as I have the jspdf.js in there

Comment: Where is the code that uses jsPDF? Also, when the app starts, can you access it in the browser console?

Comment: Now the error disappeared, and a new one appeared: Can't find variable: saveAs, because I added doc.save('test.pdf')

Answer (score 0):

use html-pdf npm package to create dynamic html to pdf file. its very easy to use

Steps:

1. create html file for report layout design
2. pass dynamic data in json format by SRS templating methods and get html code.
3. pass html code in following function

Code here:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf`enter code here`', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
});
```

where html stand for HTML Code.

visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf